# What scaling law does the two-dimensional isotropic turbulent energy spectrum satisfy as k tends to 0?

Tags: turbulence

What scaling law does the two-dimensional isotropic turbulent energy spectrum satisfy as k tends to 0? Can you recommend some references? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.